# Programmatically set IIS Authentication model for a specific asp.net file

Tags: asp.net, iis

I need to set the Authentication model of a specific asp.net file in my IIS webservice application. Topic "How do I programmatically set Integrated Windows Authentication in IIS on a .NET web service?" basically does what I want, but for an entire site. I need to have all but one of my webservices anonymous access, but one needs to use "Windows Authentication"

Like So:

[image]

I cannot figure out how to specify a certain file when applying this code:

```
String applicationPath = String.Format("{0}/{1}", _server.Sites["Default Web Site"].Name, "AppName"); 

Configuration config = _server.GetApplicationHostConfiguration(); 

ConfigurationSection anonymousAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication", applicationPath); 

anonymousAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = false; 

ConfigurationSection windowsAuthenticationSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/security/authentication/windowsAuthentication", applicationPath); 

windowsAuthenticationSection["enabled"] = true; 

_server.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the location node of the web.config file to configure specific directories/files of the application. or if you don't want to clutter the root web.config you can create additional web.config files in the sub-directories.